# Issue with compiling swf file?

Tags: flash, jquery-webcam-plugin

I want to change the [jquery webcam plugin](http://www.xarg.org/project/jquery-webcam-plugin/) flash movie size. For this we have to do the following *(according to what i have searched from google)* :

We have to change the dimensions in action script **jscam.as** file and in xml **jscam.xml** file come with plugin. And than we have to recompile the *action script (jscam.as)* file to generate updated say *updated.swf* file.

For recompiling the action script file we have to download :

[**Swfmill**](http://swfmill.org/) : It will create a new swf *(updated.swf)* file from an xml *(jscam.xml)* file.

*Command i used for generating swf file from xml file:*

> **D:\Flash\swfmill\swfmill-0.2-win32>** swfmill simple D:\Test\jQuery-webcam-master\xml\jscam.xml D:\Test\jQuery-webcam-master\swf\updated.swf

[**Mtasc**](http://www.mtasc.org/) : It will compile the main action script file *(jscam.as)* and update the above generated swf file *(updated.swf through swfmill)*.

*Command i used for compiling action script file (jscam.as) file:*

> **D:\Softwares\Flash\MTASC compiler\mtasc-1.14>** *mtasc -v -wimp -swf D:\Test\jQuery-
>   webcam-master\swf\updated.swf -main jscam.as -version 8 -cp D:\Test\jQuery-webcam-master\src*

The above process completed successfully (without a single issue) and a new *updated.swf* file was created. But when i used that file in my project, than instead of showing flash movie, it shows **blank white screen** and than i open it as a individual file in browser than also the same blank white screen is shown.

I have lost my whole day in this. I never deal with any flash project. Can anyone out there help me to solve this issue and please point me out what i am doing wrong or what i am missing ?

Thanks.

Comment: Strange! not a single reply :(

Comment: I am still waiting for the solution, hope some can solve this for me :)

Comment: You probably got no answers so far because you named and tagged your question badly (in my opinion). Your issue has nothing to do jquery. You are having problems compiling an swf file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of swfmill `D:\Flash\swfmill\swfmill-0.2-win32>`.
Since a `2.0.12` version, as recommended by the plugin author, doesn't exist, I assumed he meant 0.2.12, and it worked.

As I went through the download pages for the projects you listed, I just noticed they are quite old. I don't know your project, but have you considered any other solution like html5? - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Or if you need to stick to flash, there are other options too. I have never used this one, but I can see the latest release was issued last month, and documentation doesn't say anything about recompiling to change dimensions - http://www.scriptcam.com/